# Why am I getting the error MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted Object code: -32603, message: "execution reverted"?

Tags: solidity, metamask, nft, rinkeby, smart-contract-wallets

After successfully minting 4 ERC271 NFTs from my contract I suddenly got this error and am unable to mint more?

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted 
Object { code: -32603, message: "execution reverted"

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032","message":"execution reverted"}}}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x2E0fEc1b0D2E6dFd42B1e4e19Ad6ea9F62FA690E","to":"0x5380D4E809DD5A71C533d236782D73Dd41D94fF9","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x038d7ea4c68000"},"data":"0x0733c98500000000000000000000000012b600e5c4b926d005ba4602fce69351874595e1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000146b656570696e2069742073686f727420494c5921000000000000000000000000","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.5.3)
```

I am confused as to why it didn't happen the first time I minted and only threw the error on the 4th go. The contract address is correct and I have plenty of Eth (rinkeby) in the wallet. I have replicated the issue twice, the error is always on the 4th attempt after having minted 3 nfts perfectly fine before.

This is my solidity contract code,

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

// We need to import the helper functions from the contract that we copy/pasted.
import { Base64 } from "./libraries/Base64.sol";

contract ValNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter; //changed this back from adding 'counter', for minted amount but not sure why

    // the maximum number of NFTs that will be mintable.
    // Passed this limit, subsequent minting attempts would result in an error.
    uint256 mintCap = 142;
  //nft price
    uint public constant PRICE = 0.001 ether;

  // We split the SVG at the part where it asks for the background color.
  string svgPartOne = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='400' height='400' viewBox='0 0 240 240'><rect width='100%' height='100%' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='10' fill='";
  //and then when it asks for heart color
  string svgPartTwo = "'/><filter id='blur' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse'><feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='4' /><feBlend in='SourceGraphic' mode='multiply' /></filter><g transform='translate(100 110)'><path fill='";

  // Declare a bunch of colors for square.
  string[] colors = [ "#8B0000", "maroon", "#670A0A", "#B22222", "Orange", "#FFee00", "#FFD700", "#9ACD32", "#3CB371", "#1E90FF", "purple", "#483D8B", "#B0C4DE", "#0ABAB5", "#732982"];

  // Declare colors for heart
  string[] hcolors = ["#ffc0cb", "#ffa6c9", "#DB7093", "#FF69B4", "#f7bfbe", "#FFB3BF", "#FFB6C1", "#fe6c9e", "#DE3163", "#fc8eac"];

  event NewValNFTMinted(address recipient, uint256 tokenId, uint256 mintCap);

  constructor() ERC721 ("ValentiNFT Originals", "VNFTS") {
    console.log("This is my NFT contract. Woahah!");
  }

// function to find out how many have already been minted, related to how many are mintable total
    function getMintedAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIdCounter.current();
    }

// function to find get mintcap
    function getMintCap() public view returns (uint256) {
        return mintCap;
    }

  // Same old stuff, pick a random color for square.
  function pickRandomColor(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
    uint256 rand = random(string(abi.encodePacked("COLOR", Strings.toString(tokenId))));
    rand = rand % colors.length;
    return colors[rand];
  }

  //pick a random color for heart
  function pickRandomhColor(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
    uint256 rand = random(string(abi.encodePacked("HCOLOR", Strings.toString(tokenId))));
    rand = rand % colors.length;
    return hcolors[rand];
  }

  function random(string memory input) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input)));
  }

//FUNCTION TO MINT!
  function MintanNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI) public payable {
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIdCounter.current();

    // if mintCap has been reached, throw an error!
        require(newItemId < mintCap, "All 142 NFTs have now been minted! Woah!");

    //if not enough money then no nft
        require(msg.value >= PRICE, "Not enough ETH sent; check price!");


    // Add the random color in.
    string memory randomColor = pickRandomColor(newItemId);
    string memory hrandomColor = pickRandomhColor(newItemId);

      string memory finalSvg = string(abi.encodePacked(svgPartOne, randomColor, svgPartTwo, hrandomColor, "' transform='translate(-35 -35)' filter='url(#blur)' stroke='#FFB6C1' stroke-width='1' d='M92.71 7.27c-9.71-9.69-25.46-9.69-35.18 0L50 14.79l-7.54-7.52C32.75-2.42 17-2.42 7.29 7.27s-9.71 25.41 0 35.1L50 85l42.71-42.63c9.72-9.69 9.72-25.41 0-35.1z'/><animateTransform attributeName='transform' type='scale' values='1; 1.5; 1.25; 1.5; 1.5; 1;' dur='1s' repeatCount='indefinite' additive='sum'/></g></svg>"));

    string memory json = Base64.encode(
        bytes(
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    '{"name": "',
                    tokenURI, 
                    '", "description": "Happy Valentines Day!", "image": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,',
                    Base64.encode(bytes(finalSvg)),
                    '"}'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    string memory finalTokenUri = string(
        abi.encodePacked("data:application/json;base64,", json)
    );

    console.log("\n--------------------");
    console.log(finalTokenUri);
    console.log("--------------------\n");

    _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
  
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, finalTokenUri);
  
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    console.log("An NFT w/ ID %s has been minted to %s", newItemId, recipient);
    emit NewValNFTMinted(recipient, newItemId, getMintCap());

  }

  function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
     uint balance = address(this).balance;
     require(balance > 0, "No ether left to withdraw");     (bool success, ) = (msg.sender).call{value: balance}("");
     require(success, "Transfer failed.");
}
}
```

I assume it is a problem in the contract and not on the front end? But  why would it work for 3 mints and then throw this error? I thought if there was a problem with the contract it would have thrown the error the first time trying to mint? I have tried shortening the strings as I thought it might be that, but it didn't help and the same error happened after 4 mints. I just cannot figure out the issue?? Thanks

EDIT:
I have also tried to fix the issue using ethers `estimateGas` to check the amount of gas required to call the mint function, but I get the same error. Again, always after 3 mints, the 4 4th doesnt work. This is my mint function code

```
const MintNft = async () => {
    try {
        const { ethereum } = window;
 
        if (ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, Token.abi, signer);

      /* 
      Show the loading indicator*/
      setMintingNft(true);
      console.log('Minting NFT in progress...');

      let gasLimit = await contract.estimateGas.MintanNFT(userAccount, userMessage);
      
      const transation = await contract.MintanNFT(userAccount, userMessage, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001")});
      await transation.wait(); 

              /*
              Hide the loading indicator when minting is finished*/
      setMintingNft(false);

    console.log(`NFT is minted woohoo!`);

    // clearing the values from the input boxes
         setUserAccount("");    
         setUserMessage("");
    } else {
        console.log("ethereum object does not exist");
      }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    alert(`There was an error, you probably didnt put in an ETH address please try again`);

    /*
     If there is a problem/error, hide the loading indicator*/
    setMintingNft(false);
  }
}
```

and also my deploy.js code

```
async function main () {
  
  const ValNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("ValNFT");
  console.log('Deploying Val...');
  
  const valnft = await ValNFT.deploy();
  await valnft.deployed();
  console.log('val deployed to:', valnft.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

EDIT.2:
Trying to fix the issue by increasing MintanNFT gas also throws an error.

```
Error: transaction failed (transactionHash="0x595c20284625df84f742e3109e19989cfce24956208e43d1bf0cc586c4d91581", transaction={"hash":"0x595c20284625df84f742e3109e19989cfce24956208e43d1bf0cc586c4d91581","type":2,"accessList":null,"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0xDB7b5d24fF72807367efAC408ac54978d0f61eb0","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9f114c80"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x908a9040"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9f114c80"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1e8480"},"to":"0x6F42f0E66821c7C16685d8491F4Fd65CF2432eF8","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"nonce":31,"data":"0x0733c985000000000000000000000000ad399b9f20f2e0316e27d6481287a7d4ab65f509000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000086e756d6265722034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","r":"0x10fbdecad96735867783edb499f4fbfb979df0fd2c923ef3328b205164b871d5","s":"0x2f2465b8c333322b8926b7992b1cdc6f2a4d2ceca2b9e9b090cccd9447bda0f5","v":1,"creates":null,"chainId":0}, receipt={"to":"0x6F42f0E66821c7C16685d8491F4Fd65CF2432eF8","from":"0xDB7b5d24fF72807367efAC408ac54978d0f61eb0","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":29,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9e00"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockHash":"0x039ef55be3dcafb097c7779776107752c18ecb94acdde13a15e87610f3188087","transactionHash":"0x595c20284625df84f742e3109e19989cfce24956208e43d1bf0cc586c4d91581","logs":[],"blockNumber":10144563,"confirmations":1,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x018634d6"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x9f114c80"},"status":0,"type":2,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.5.3)
```

I am wondering at this point if the 4th svg is just to big to mint or if I did something wrong on my contract?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set the gas price? start with 2M gas.

Comment: I did try to set the gas price in the deploy.js script that caused an error deploying the contract, in Etherscan it showed 'Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [contract creation code storage out of gas].  Is there another way to explicitly set the gas price?

Comment: the deploy.js code i used to try and set gas price `async function main () {

  const ValNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("ValNFT");
  console.log('Deploying Val...');
  

  const valnft = await ValNFT.deploy({gasLimit:3000000});
  console.log('val deployed to:', valnft.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });`

Comment: Why did you change the deploy gas? You mentioned that the problem was when minting. You can edit your own questions to add more details.

Comment: yes, the error came up when minting. I changed the deploy gas as I wasnt sure if that's what you mean by explicitly set the gas price, and had read on a similar thread that it had worked for them, so I was trying different ways to fix. It didn't work so have reverted deploy.js back to what it was originally, without the gas, and now getting the same error as I got to start with again.  Have edited question to show what else i have tried and updated code. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try increasing `MintanNFT` gas?

Comment: No, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: I think something like `contract.MintanNFT(userAccount, userMessage, { value: ..., gasLimit: 2000000 })`, or change to something above what estimateGas returns.

Comment: thank you! I tried this, up to 10000000, and although it started minting, it still threw an error and didn't manage to mint. I have added this to the original question. I'm still stumped.

Comment: The transaction `0x595c20284625df84f742e3109e19989cfce24956208e43d1bf0cc586c4d91581` looking at etherscan very little gas is used 18512 so it is likely it fails at the beginning.